# Adding object images into Excel using EPPlus

Tags: c#, excel

I want to add an image to excel object. I added a picture on and now I want to add the object image to the image when I click on it in excel, it will zoom up to me.
like this

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ttl3X.png)

and here is my code:

```
 private void AddImage(ExcelWorksheet oSheet, int rowIndex, int colIndex, string imagePath)
    {
        Image logo = Image.FromFile(imagePath);
        ExcelPicture excelImage = null;
        if (logo != null)
        {
            excelImage = oSheet.Drawings.AddPicture("", logo);
            excelImage.From.Column = colIndex;
            excelImage.From.Row = rowIndex;
            excelImage.SetSize(100, 100);
            // 2x2 px space for better alignment
            excelImage.From.ColumnOff = Pixel2MTU(2);
            excelImage.From.RowOff = Pixel2MTU(2);
        }
    }

    public int Pixel2MTU(int pixels)
    {
        int mtus = pixels * 9525;
        return mtus;
    }
```

Thanks.

I desired result is like this

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rsouw.png)

Comment: You forgot to ask a question. What is your result and what exactly did you expect instead of that result?

Comment: I desired result is as the picture I posted on the attached picture